# Changing version of assemblyInfo file does not work

Tags: c#, perl, visual-studio-addins

I have a batch file which changes the version of AssemblyInfo cs file in order to update the version of the output dll. my script uses a perl script and includes those lines:

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"\vsvars32.bat
ATTRIB -R "MyProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
perl.exe UpdateVersion.pl 1 2 3 4 "MyProject\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
pushd .
cd Project
devenv /rebuild release /out .\build.log MyProject.csproj 
popd
```

This script works well for a regular C# project but does not work for an Addin project.
When I run this on an Addin project the assemblyInfo file becomes dirty with gibberish.
Is there any idea for this behavior?
and how can I change the version of addin.dll via batch file?

Comment: How it is possible to answer this question without the Perl script is beyond me.